# When did scientists first experimentally measure wavelengths of EM radiation? How?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, measurements, history, wavelength

When did someone first discover that short wavelength light has higher energy than long?

And can gamma ray wavelengths be measured, even today?

Comment: These are two distinct questions. Please ask one question per post. Also there is no evidence of prior research.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the history of science and mathematics stackexchange: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It was back in 1789, when Thomas Young proposed a new experiment to show the wave nature of light. Although Newton observed bright and dark pattern of light under certain circumstances, Young was the first to explain these patterns with the wave nature of light.

He used a candle and a card with a rectangular hole, where he stretched a human hair.
Hes used his observations to measure the wavelength of light which proves that light indeed acts as a wave.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light

> > “I therefore made a rectangular hole in a card, and bent its ends so as to support a hair parallel to the sides
> >     of the hole; then, upon applying the eye near the hole, the hair, of course, appeared dilated by indistinct
> >     vision into a surface, of which the breadth was determined by the distance of the hair and the magnitude of
> >     the hole, independently of the temporary aperture of the pupil. When the hair approached so near to the
> >     direction of the margin of a candle that the inflected light was sufficiently copious to produce a sensible
> >     effect, the fringes [alternating bands] began to appear; and it was easy to estimate the proportion of their
> >     breadth to the apparent breadth of the hair across the image of which they extended. I found that six of the
> >     brightest red fringes, nearly at equal distance, occupied the whole of that image. The breadth of the aperture
> >     was 66/1000 [of an inch], and its distance from the hair 8/10 of an inch; the diameter of the hair was ... 1/600
> >     [of an inch]. Hence, we have 11/1000 for the deviation of the first red fringe at the distance of 8/10; and as
> >     8/10 / 11/1000 = 1/600 / 11/480000, or 1/43636 [of an inch] for the difference of the routes of the red light
> >     where it was most intense.”

https://www.dartmouth.edu/~phys1/labs/lab2.pdf

Comment: It was the Dutch scientist Christiaan Huygens who proposed the wave theory of light in 1678, long before Young. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens

Comment: @my2cts the question was experimentally measure the wavelength. That was Young.

Comment: Surprisingly, AFAIK it was not until Hertz in ca. 1886 that the wavelength of radio waves was measured.

Answer (score -1):

Your first question is about the history of physics. Perhaps there is a more suitable site to ask it.

It was the Dutch scientist Christiaan Huygens who proposed the wave theory of light in 1678, long before Young. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens . Although Huygens' theory does not talk about interference, Huygens considered light to behave like a wave, like water (page 4 of his treatise, http://www.gutenberg.org/files/14725/14725-h/14725-h.htm). Clearly waves have a frequency, a wave length and a speed. Nevertheless he did not discuss this. Note that if he had, acceptance of his work would likely have been negatively impacted by the influence of Newton, as has been the work on differential calculus of Leibniz. Newton had a competing theory of light as consisting of particles. Wave particle duality "avant la la lettre" !

Once you know that light is a wave - of course now we know that it consists of quanta described by a wave - and that it has a finite velocity  ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_Rømer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_R%C3%B8mer)) - then you can surmise that higher frequencies correspond to higher energy for the same amplitude. The full theory was developed and published by Fresnel and Young.

As to your second question, it is too broad. There are many ways to detect gamma rays as you can find out by web search.